# Selecting different columns in SWT Table, using JFace TableViewer

Tags: swt, jface

I have a 2-column SWT Table that uses TableViewer. Trouble is that I can only select (and edit) cells in the first column -- clicking on the second column does nothing.

I read from somewhere (lost the link) that there's no easy way to get such functionality (!) -- you're supposed to mess around with several extra concepts if you want to select (and edit) different columns in your table.

This snippet
([http://www.goneeded.com/snippet/eclipse/JFace/Viewers/Snippet035TableCursorCellHighlighter.html](http://www.goneeded.com/snippet/eclipse/JFace/Viewers))
seems to be relevant, but it's not clear which part of it is necessary and it has depenendencies to other snippets. I tried to get it working but it did nothing.

Seems that new table editing and cell-selecting features were added in Eclipse 3.3 -- is there a tutorial or smth available on how to use them? The snippets are too cryptic for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to edit and select cells independently.  You might have the SWT.FULL_SELECTION style bit set on the Table constructor.  That forces every selection to span the whole row instead of a single cell.

I'd check out this tutorial for more on TableViewers:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/table_viewer.html

Comment: Actually, I used this tutorial (among others :)) but no success. I got it working so that it allows selecting and editing *sometimes* :). For now I've alreade given up and I'm using structured text in a Text instead of Table. Thanks anyway!